# Conditionally remove row from data frame using dates and means

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'd like to conditionally remove row from data frame using dates and means. In my example:

```
# Package
library(tidyverse)

# Open dataset
RES_all_files_better <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/RES_all_files_better_df.csv")
str(RES_all_files_better)
# 'data.frame': 507 obs. of  11 variables:
#  $ STAND     : chr  "ARROIOXAVIER024B" "ARROIOXAVIER024B" "ARROIOXAVIER024B" "ARROIOXAVIER024B" ...
#  $ ESPACAMENT: int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
#  $ ESPECIE   : chr  "benthamii" "benthamii" "benthamii" "benthamii" ...
#  $ IDADE     : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 ...
#  $ DATE_S2   : chr  "2019-01-28" "2019-02-22" "2019-03-24" "2019-05-18" ...
#  $ NDVI_avg  : num  0.877 0.895 0.879 0.912 0.908 ...
#  $ NDVI_sd   : num  0.0916 0.0808 0.0758 0.1175 0.1132 ...
#  $ NDVI_min  : num  -0.235 -0.1783 0.0844 -0.5666 -0.6093 ...
#  $ NDVI_max  : num  0.985 0.998 0.993 0.999 0.999 ...
#  $ MONTH     : int  1 2 3 5 7 8 9 11 12 12 ...
#  $ NDVI_ref  : num  0.823 0.823 0.823 0.823 0.823 ...
```

In my case, I search some operation for remove rows in data set, if `NDVI_max+NDVI_min/2` is lower than `NDVI_avg` grouped by `(ESPACAMENT,ESPECIE,IDADE)` in the date (`DATE_S2`) before the actual date. An example for `RES_all_files_better$STAND=="QUEBRACANGA012F"`:

```
# Original dataset:
              STAND    DATE_S2  NDVI_avg  NDVI_min  NDVI_max
...
208 QUEBRACANGA012F 2021-08-30 0.8748818 0.8238573 0.9072955
209 QUEBRACANGA012F 2021-11-08 0.5707210 0.2847520 0.8908801
210 QUEBRACANGA012F 2021-11-13 0.5515253 0.2275358 0.8940712
211 QUEBRACANGA012F 2021-12-28 0.5956103 0.2469136 0.9122636
212 QUEBRACANGA012F 2022-01-12 0.5952482 0.2084076 0.9031508
213 QUEBRACANGA012F 2022-01-22 0.5773518 0.2088580 0.8783236
214 QUEBRACANGA012F 2022-02-16 0.4246735 0.1674446 0.6224726
215 QUEBRACANGA012F 2022-02-26 0.4064463 0.1378491 0.6111995

#Final dataset:
              STAND    DATE_S2  NDVI_avg  NDVI_min  NDVI_max
...
208 QUEBRACANGA012F 2021-08-30 0.8748818 0.8238573 0.9072955
```

The lines 209 to 215 were removed because `(NDVI_max+NDVI_min/2)=0.5878161` that is lower than `NDVI_avg = 0.8748818` in last date `2021-08-30`.

Please, any help with it?

Comment: when you say last date, is it the earliest date?

Comment: i.e. `RES_all_files_better %>% mutate(DATE_S2 = as.Date(DATE_S2)) %>% group_by(ESPACAMENT,ESPECIE,IDADE) %>% filter((NDVI_max+NDVI_min/2) > NDVI_avg[which.min(DATE_S2)]) %>% ungroup`

Comment: Thanks @akrun is the last date that happens low `(NDVI_max+NDVI_min/2)` and after that remove all. This is because I remove lines 209 to 215 and just line 209 satisfy my inicial condition.

Comment: I get a value of 0.68 i.e. if you filter by the one you showed `RES_all_files_better %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% filter(STAND == "QUEBRACANGA012F") %>% mutate(DATE_S2 = as.Date(DATE_S2)) %>% mutate(New = (NDVI_max+NDVI_min/2)) %>% slice_min(n = 1, order_by = New)`

Comment: Did you meant `RES_all_files_better %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% filter(STAND == "QUEBRACANGA012F") %>% mutate(DATE_S2 = as.Date(DATE_S2)) %>% mutate(New = (NDVI_max+NDVI_min/2)) %>% filter(NDVI_avg > min(New)) %>% pull(rn)
 [1] 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199
[31] 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208`

Comment: If that is correct. then you get 336 rows as final output `RES_all_files_better %>% mutate(rn = row_number(), DATE_S2 = as.Date(DATE_S2)) %>% group_by(ESPACAMENT,ESPECIE,IDADE) %>% mutate(New = (NDVI_max+NDVI_min/2)) %>% filter(NDVI_avg > min(New)) %>% ungroup`

Comment: RES_all_files_better2<-RES_all_files_better[RES_all_files_better$STAND=="QUEBRACANGA012F",] 
RES_all_files_better2[,-c(2:4,7,10:11)]
              STAND    DATE_S2  NDVI_avg  NDVI_min  NDVI_max
170 QUEBRACANGA012F 2019-02-22 0.9246810 0.9107569 0.9333001
171 QUEBRACANGA012F 2019-03-24 0.9263106 0.9109188 0.9365979
172 QUEBRACANGA012F 2019-07-07 0.9230092 0.8448208 0.9868020
...
209 QUEBRACANGA012F 2021-11-08 0.5707210 0.2847520 0.8908801
210 QUEBRACANGA012F 2021-11-13 0.5515253 0.2275358 0.8940712
I have bad rows yet, @akrun

Comment: I tried your subset data, but the value I couldn't find `0.5878161` from the computation

Comment: Thanks @akrun my bad, problem solved!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to `filter` on the `min` computed value ('new')

```
library(dplyr)
RES_all_files_better %>% 
  # convert to `Date` class and create a sequence column for checking
  mutate(rn = row_number(), DATE_S2 = as.Date(DATE_S2)) %>% 
  # grouped by columns
  group_by(ESPACAMENT,ESPECIE,IDADE) %>%
  # create computed column
  mutate(New = (NDVI_max+NDVI_min/2)) %>% 
  # filter the rows where the NDVI_avg is greater than the minimum value
  filter(NDVI_avg > min(New)) %>% 
  ungroup #%>%
  # select(-rn, -New)
```